# How do I show info from two different models / adapters in one recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have two Models (ModelChat and ModelUsers) and their class adapters (PostsAdapter  and  AllUsersAdapter).
I want to get and set user info such as name and email from the ModelUser and get and set post information from the ModelPost from Firebase database into the same recyclerview in my HomeActivity.
The codes are as shown below:

PostsAdapter.java

public class PostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsAdapter.MyHolder>{

```
Context context;
List<ModelPost> postList;

public PostsAdapter(Context context, List<ModelPost> postList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.postList = postList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //inflate layout row_post.xml
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_posts, parent, false);
    return new MyHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {
    //get data
    String userUID = postList.get(position).getUserUID();
    String userEmail = postList.get(position).getUserEmail();
    String userProfilePic = postList.get(position).getUserProfilePic();
    String firstName = postList.get(position).getUserFirstName();
    String lastName = postList.get(position).getUserLastName();
    String userNickName = postList.get(position).getUserNickName();
    String postTimeStamp = postList.get(position).getPostTime();
    String userPost = postList.get(position).getUserPost();

    //set data
    //set data
    Glide
            .with(context)
            .load(userProfilePic)
            .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
            .into(holder.avatarTv);
    holder.firstnameTv.setText(firstName);
    holder.lastnameTv.setText(lastName);
    holder.nicknameTv.setText(userNickName);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return postList.size();
}

//view holder class
class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //views from row_posts layout


    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        //init view
        //my views here
    }
}
```

}

AllUsersAdapter.java

public class AllUsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllUsersAdapter.MyHolder>{

```
Context context;
List<ModelUser> userList;

//Constructor > Generate
public AllUsersAdapter(Context context, List<ModelUser> userList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.userList = userList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //Inflate layout (row_user)
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_all_users, parent, false);

    return new MyHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {
    //get data
    String userUID = userList.get(position).getUid();
    String userProfilePic = userList.get(position).getProfilepic();
    String userName = userList.get(position).getFirstname() + " " + userList.get(position).getLastname();
    String userNickname = userList.get(position).getNickname();
    String userStatus = userList.get(position).getStatus();

    //set data
    Glide
            .with(context)
            .load(userProfilePic)
            .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
            .into(holder.mAvatarIv);

    holder.mNameTv.setText(userName);
    holder.mNicknameTv.setText(userNickname);
    holder.mStatusTv.setText(userStatus);

    //Handle item click
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*Click user from user list to start conversation
             *Start Activity by putting UID of receiver
             *we will use that UID to identify the user we are gonna chat */

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("userUid", userUID);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userList.size();
}

class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        //init my views here

    }
}
```

}

HomeActivity.java

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<ModelPost> postList;
PostsAdapter postsAdapter;

String mUID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    //recyclerview and its properties
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.posts_recyclerview);

    //init post list
    postList = new ArrayList<>();

    loadPosts();

}

private void loadPosts() {
    //path of all posts
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
    //get all data from this reference
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            postList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                ModelPost modelPost = ds.getValue(ModelPost.class);

                postList.add(modelPost);

                //adapter
                postsAdapter = new PostsAdapter(HomeActivity.this, postList);
                //set adapter to recyclerview
                recyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            //in case of errors
            //Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, ""+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Any screenshot of the desired UI.

Comment: I think you need to merge your data into a single list first, then define a single adapter that defines the UI.

Comment: Currently I'm unable to post images. But what I want to achieve is: I need each full post to be in a one row in the recyclerview. Just like a Twitter post, user avatar, name and post in the same row but getting the data from different adapters/ models as I have explained above.

Comment: Manipulate the data first, such that each list item in a single list contains all the data you would want to display. Then work to define a single adapter.

Comment: It would help if you can give an example basing on my provided code above. Because currently the custom list view (row_post.xml) I am using contains all the fields I want. The problem I am facing is setting the data from two different models or even combining data to display in one adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ConcatAdapter.

> An RecyclerView.Adapter implementation that presents the contents of multiple adapters in sequence. [More info](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter)

Concatenate adapters sequentially with ConcatAdapter:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/merge-adapters-sequentially-with-mergeadapter-294d2942127a

Comment: I need each full post to be in a one row in the recyclerview. Just like a Twitter post, user avatar, name and post in the same row but getting the data from different adapters/ models as I have explained above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help

```
 MyAdapter adapter1 = ...;
 AnotherAdapter adapter2 = ...;
 ConcatAdapter concatenated = new ConcatAdapter(adapter1, adapter2);
 recyclerView.setAdapter(concatenated);
```